# React serve -s build, The term 'serve' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: reactjs, build, serve

Hello I am trying to build my react app so I did `yarn build` and it created the necessary folder now I am trying to do `serve -s build` and it's telling me the error below

[image: Error]

** I have tried to uninstall and reinstall serve by `npm uninstall -g serve` and `npm install -g serve`
and I found the serve folder in `C:\Users\Nairi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try `npx serve -s build` I don't know why but they happened to me also and this worked

Answer (score 6):

**Solution1**:

`yarn global add serve`

Based on [NPM - Doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve),  you can install it globally `yarn global add serve`, then use it as you want like `serve -s build`

**Solution2: npx**:

`npx serve -s build`

As this [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/npm-vs-npx-whats-the-difference/) says, `npx` will check whether `<command>` or `<package>` exists in `$PATH`, or in the local project binaries(`node_modules`), and if so it will execute it, and if it's not there, it will download it. You can also run packages from github
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your admin permissions, so it can install globally with the -g flag

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone still needs this but you can use this
`yarn global add serve` - Once this is successful, do `yarn serve -s build`. This worked for me!